# Convert MongoDB ISODate format to normal PHP readable date format

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7.1

I have a collection which has date as field with mongoDB ISODate type. Whenever I tried to get data from that collection in ascending order it works fine but that date field return as Array which is not readable via PHP.
Sample response of MongoDB result :

```
[date] => Array([$date] => Array([$numberLong] => 1496203500000))
```

I had tried to convert that array to MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime Object but that didn't worked. 
Please let me know the way to convert that array to php readable.

This is not related to conversion of normal timestamp value to MongoDB Date format. I need this conversion when I get date in response of mongo query from PHP. While doing so I am getting array as I provided sample format of the same which I can't read from PHP. That date is not even simple timestamp and even that keys are also not accessible via PHP.

PHP Version :- 7.1
MongoDB Version :- 3.4

here is my sample code to understand the scenario:

insert.php

```
<?php
   $connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
   $mongodb = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager($connectionString);
   $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
   $writeConcern = new \MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(
                \MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 100);

   $timestamp = 1453939200 * 1000;
   $utcdatetime = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($timestamp);
   $projection = ["insertion" => $utcdatetime];
   $query->insert($projection);
   $result = $mongodb->executeBulkWrite("test.datetest",$query, 
   $writeConcern);
```

read.php

```
<?php
  $connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
  $mongodb = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager($connectionString);

  $options = ["sort" => ["insertion" => -1], "limit" => 10];
  $filter = array();

  $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter,$options);
  $cursor = $mongodb->executeQuery("test.datetest", $query);

  foreach($cursor as $key => $row) {
     print_r(json_decode(json_encode($row), true)); 
  }
```

In response I am getting date array instead of plan timestamp as follows:

```
Array
(
   [_id] => Array
    (
        [$oid] => 5937c857c3f42b49eb626ce2
    )

   [insertion] => Array
    (
        [$date] => Array
            (
                [$numberLong] => 1453939200000
            )

    )

)
```

From above response I can't able to read $numberLong field from array via PHP. While doing so it gives me blank array. Due to this I am not able to convert that date into normal user readable date.

Comment: @Neil Lunn might be my question was not cleared to you, so I have updated the same. This is not only simply timestamp conversion. I can't even read internal values from [date] => Array([$date] => Array([$numberLong] => 1496203500000)) array. I know how to convert timestamp to MongoDB ISODate format, by using so I inserted this record in collection, but while reading I can't able to convert that value back to php readable date

Comment: No pretty clear. It is actually answered in the linked question.

Comment: @Neill Lunn steps to reproduce this issue are as follows:
1 - Insert date in mongoDb collection in ISODate format
2 - Then read that same date via php
3 - Then convert that date in normal date time format.

Comment: Exactly what the linked answer(s) show you how to do. Please read it. You are not the first to ever ask.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have pest my sample code for your reference, I hope so that will help you to understand my problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have the same difficulty as Mayr and your linked answer does not solve this question.