# MongoDB returns strange date format when querying from PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection which documents contain an ISODate field. This value was stored via PHP.
However, when retrieving data from this collection, I get the date in a strange format, which I can't read nor transform with PHP. If I make a var_dump, I get this:

```
array(1) { ["$date"]=> array(1) { ["$numberLong"]=> string(13) "1588356428662" } }
```

Although it might look like a standard array, I can't access the values (not with index numbers neither keys).
I think the field $numberLong might be the number of milliseconds from the epoch or something like that. However, as I cannot access the value, I can't try to transform it anyway.
This problem was already asked in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406148/convert-mongodb-isodate-format-to-normal-php-readable-date-format), which was closed as duplicate. However, the user didn't get the answer, because the recommended answer had nothing to do with what he was really asking.

I've searched the whole internet and I just found that thread with no answers. There's nothing in PHP manuals. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the best way to solve this problem, but the following code worked for me:

```
function parseDate($datefromMongo){
    ob_start(); //In order to redirect the output of var_dump to variable $str
    var_dump($dateFromMongo); 
    $str = ob_get_clean();  

    $pieces = explode("string", $str); //To get only the string
    $pieces = explode('"', $pieces[1]); //To remove quote marks
    $millis = intval($pieces[1]); //Casting from string to integer

    //$millis is the number of milliseconds from the epoch.
    /*Function date only accepts a precission of 10 digits, and $millis has the 
    unix timestamp format (13 digits), so we divide by 1000*/

    return date("D, d F Y, G:i", ($millis/1000));

    //The string passed to date is the format expected on output, you can set which you want
}
```

I hope this can be helpful for anyone!